# dealing with the Lables using the function of scale_x_datetime in ggolot2 in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, label

I have some problems which looks very simple, but I could not figure out, when I used the function of scale_x_datetime. Please the the graphs below:
[image]

What I want to get in the graph:

1) the x label only with time (for example: 00:00:00)
2) the first value of x label should be 00:00:00

for the first point, I used the **scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%X")** to only get the time from the date_time. But then i got the graph below:

[image]

the line looks correct like the first graph, but the responding x-axis value is wrong.

for the second point which I want to get, I tried to use the function limits in   *scale_x_datetime*, but it does not work at all

Someone has tips for it?

Thanks a lot

Note:

to generate the data table:

```
dd <- data.table(date = c("2015-07-01 00:15:00", "2015-07-01 00:30:00", "2015-07-01 00:45:00","2015-07-01 01:00:00", "2015-07-01 01:15:00","2015-07-01 01:30:00","2015-07-01 01:45:00","2015-07-01 02:00:00","2015-07-01 02:15:00", "2015-07-01 02:30:00"),value = c(1.83,1.68,1.29,14.23,0.96, 1.29,10.4,8.25,6.77,7.66))

dd$date<-as.POSIXct(dd$date)
```

for the first graph: I used the code below:

```
p22 <- ggplot(dd, aes(dd$date, dd$value))+labs(x="Time", y="seconds")
p22 <-p22 + geom_line(colour="dark blue",size=1) 
p22<- p22+scale_x_datetime(date_breaks  = "15 mins") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

it looks fine, but I want to just show the time , so I added the code **date_labels = "%X"** to just get the time value from the date_time : below:

```
p22 <- ggplot(dd, aes(dd$date, dd$value))+labs(x="Time", y="seconds")
p22 <-p22 + geom_line(colour="dark blue",size=1) 
p22<- p22+scale_x_datetime(date_breaks  = "15 mins",date_labels = "%X") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

and then, I got the error, since the responding x value in the second graph is wrong.  It could be the problem of timezone, but not sure for it.

Comment: This looks like a timezone issue. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: you do realize that your data set crosses a day boundary (look at the labels on the first graph), which is why the "time" isn't starting at `00:00:00`, right? if they should not be crossing a day boundary, then you have either a data problem or a time zone issue when reading/converting/munging your data.

Comment: hi , all , thanks for the attention, first , my dataset is start from 00:15:00, but i want to set it start from 00:00:00. i just posted the original code for the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vjust = 0.5` to get what you want in either case.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dd = data_frame(
  date = c("2015-07-01 00:15:00", "2015-07-01 00:30:00", "2015-07-01 00:45:00","2015-07-01 01:00:00", "2015-07-01 01:15:00","2015-07-01 01:30:00","2015-07-01 01:45:00","2015-07-01 02:00:00","2015-07-01 02:15:00", "2015-07-01 02:30:00"),
  value = c(1.83,1.68,1.29,14.23,0.96, 1.29,10.4,8.25,6.77,7.66)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    as.POSIXct(date)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  labs(x = "Time", y = "seconds") +
  geom_line(colour = "dark blue", size = 1) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks  = "15 mins") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your datetime values have an explicit time zone:

```
dd <- data.frame(date = c("2015-07-01 00:15:00", "2015-07-01 00:30:00", 
                          "2015-07-01 00:45:00","2015-07-01 01:00:00", 
                          "2015-07-01 01:15:00","2015-07-01 01:30:00",
                          "2015-07-01 01:45:00","2015-07-01 02:00:00",
                          "2015-07-01 02:15:00", "2015-07-01 02:30:00"),
                 value = c(1.83,1.68,1.29,14.23,0.96, 1.29,10.4,8.25,6.77,7.66))

#you should always define the time zone    
dd$date <- as.POSIXct(dd$date, tz = "GMT")

ggplot(dd, aes(date, value))+
  labs(x="Time", y="seconds") +
  geom_line(colour="dark blue",size=1) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks  = "15 mins",date_labels = "%X", 
                   limits = as.POSIXct(c("2015-07-01 00:00:00", 
                                         "2015-07-01 03:00:00"), 
                                       tz = "GMT")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

PS: Never use `$` inside `aes`. ggplot2 looks inside the data.frame passed to its `data` parameter for variables. Since it sometimes reorders this data.frame you can get unexpected results if you refer to data outside ggplot2 inside `aes`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `scale_x_date()` to scale the date axis accordingly.

For example

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%b %d")
```

will display labels for each week while each day is shown as minor points.

`limits` argument can be used to define the limits for the date range.

Note : Since sample code is not available in the original question i haven't try to get the result that you want. But it should possible to get the desired result with this method.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: hi all,  thanks for the idea, i just added the code for the problem :)